# Calling a linked server fails after a snapshot connection has been disposed

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, ado.net, snapshot

We have a C# application using ADO.NET and an SQL-Server with SNAPSHOT Transaction Isolation Level. This is 'as is' and unfortunately cannot be modified.

Now we need insert stuff on a linked server.

We execute the following code (reduced to illustrate the problem):

```
// Create a snapshot Transaction and close the connection
using (var con = new SqlConnection(myConStr)) 
{
   con.BeginTransaction(TransactionLevel.Snapshot); 
}

// do something with a linked server
using (var con = new SqlConnection(myConStr)) 
{
  using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand() 
  {
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into LinkedServer.SomeDb..Table ...";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

We get can an exception when trying to insert something into the linked server

'Remote access is not supported for transaction isolation level "SNAPSHOT"'

I wonder why it is not possible: We open the connection, make sure it is disposed (clearing all transactions, I guess) and use a second connection for the linked server call.

Executing the stuff in SSMS using plain SQL seems to work.

What are we missing? Is there a proper way to do it?

Thanks for any hints in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The secret to understand the problem is the 'connection pooling' which is done by ADO.NET in the Background. The real connection is actually set to SNAPSHOT.

In the second part of the sample code, that connection simply gets reused thus still being in 'snapshot mode'.

The solution is to explicitly set the transaction isolation Level to something else right after opening the Connection.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(myConStr)) 
{
  using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand() 
  {
     cmd.CommandText = "set transaction isolation Level read committed";
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }

  using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand() 
  {
     cmd.CommandText = "insert into LinkedServer.SomeDb..Table ...";
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```